# Hide columns values after the first

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have table, namely company, having columns Emp_name, salary and department_name

```
Emp_name       salary       Dept_name
AAAA           40000        production
HHHH           50000        Developer
DDDD           40000        production
EEEE           45000        sales
BBBB           42000        production
FFFF           46000        sales
CCCC           41000        production
GGGG           49000        Developer
```

I want all data from table as per department and I want it like as below:

```
Emp_name       salary       Dept_name
AAAA           40000        production
BBBB           42000
CCCC           41000 
DDDD           40000
EEEE           45000        sales
FFFF           46000 
GGGG           49000        Developer
HHHH           50000
```

Comment: Please explain the ordering.

Comment: Thats a display problem, something you normally do in your front end.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add an id (int identity(1,1)) column, just in case you have two workers in the same department with the same name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just ordering the rows:

```
select emp_name, salary, dept_name
from t
order by min(emp_name) over (partition by dept_name),
         dept_name,
         emp_name;
```

However, you seem to want the employee name on the first row for each grouping.  That type of transformation is often handled at the application layer.  But you can do it in SQL:

```
select emp_name, salary,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by dept_name order by emp_name) = 1
             then dept_name
        end) as dept_name
from t
order by min(emp_name) over (partition by dept_name),
         dept_name,
         emp_name;
```